# Hibernate Select Top and Bottom n Rows with Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have two tables, Books and Reviews. Reviews has a column, stars, that can have a value between 1 and 5. A Book can have many Reviews.

How would I select all books such that only the top and bottom 3 reviews for each book are returned (instead of all reviews) using the Criteria API?

If the Criteria API is not capable, I am up for other suggestions like HQL, SQL, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I'm actually surprised at how difficult this is. All solutions that involve querying for Books and each Book having its list of top and bottom Reviews results in N queries per Book on some databases, and for mine in particular (MySql) requires 3N. Of course, someone may be able to figure out a clever way around this, but my playing with the code, raw SQL, researching what others have done, database limitations, etc. appears to always come back to that.

So... I ended up flipping the problem around. Instead of calculating the top and bottom Reviews whenever I query for Books (which is a very frequent query - FYI Books/Reviews are for example purposes - the actual domain is different) I calculate the top/bottom whenever a new Review is submitted. This changes submitting a Review from one "query" into three queries, but submitting a Review is fairly infrequent compared to querying for Books.

To do this, I added two new properties to Book, topReviews and bottomReviews and mapped them as one-to-many lists on Review. I then updated the code that saves new Reviews to query for the top and bottom Reviews for the Book in question (2 queries), sets the top/bottom Reviews properties on the Book (overwriting the previous), and saves the Book. Any Book queries now return these "cached" top and bottom Reviews. I still have a lazy "reviews" property that will have all reviews (not just top/bottom) if desired - another one-to-many mapping.

I am open to other recommendations. Most answers here are in the ball park but miss the problem or won't work due to database limitations or require too many queries.

Answer (score 23):

You could always set the ordering asc/desc and then limit the results.

ex:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```

Not sure where it stands with regard to efficiency.  I'm assuming that it's doing the filtering after the fact that a `Select *` has been fired off?

Answer (score 15):

Try this and let me know if it works for you:

```
  // you should have the DAO class containing this queries 
  // extend HibernateDaoSupport

  List<Tag> topList = getSession().createQuery("FROM Reviews r WHERE r.book = " 
          + book + " ORDER BY r.stars asc").setMaxResults(3).list();

  List<Tag> bottomList = getSession().createQuery("FROM Reviews r WHERE r.book = " 
          + book + " ORDER BY r.stars desc").setMaxResults(3).list();
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I ended up adding something like this to my Review DAO but I prefer the Criteria API so I used that. The problem is, I am querying for all Books matching a certain criteria, and each one needs to have its top and bottom Reviews. It would be very inefficient and awkward to run that query then manually go through each Review, run these two queries, and tweak the response. I have settled on a different solution.

Comment: Do NOT write sql as a string concatenation. This is extremely prone to injection attacks.
Consider someone inputting this as variable book: "any; drop table Reviews"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want using a single query.  You can certainly do it in two, however (using EJBQL with named parameters):

```
SELECT r FROM Reviews r WHERE r.book = :book ORDER BY r.stars ASC LIMIT 3;
SELECT r FROM Reviews r WHERE r.book = :book ORDER BY r.stars DESC LIMIT 3;
```

And you could of course write a simple helper method that makes both of these calls and collates the results into whatever data structure you prefer.

Comment: LIMIT is RDMS specific. Don't use it. Use `setMaxResults`.

Comment: @Alex - LIMIT is also part of the [EJBQL spec](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/cmp/ejbql.xtp#LIMIT).

Comment: you are right. I never used it. He wants criteria query, though.

Comment: It also seems that the question is slightly different. He wants books not reviews. I withdrew my answer for now as I am not convinced that I am answering the right question.

Comment: @Alex - Good point, he wants to "select all books such that only the top and bottom 3 reviews for each book are returned", which I don't think is directly possible.  Usually when I want one entity to provide "automatic" custom filtering of a collection of some other entity I add an `@Transient` method to the first entity that performs the desired filtering on the backing collection and then returns the result (in a new collection instance).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using EJBQL, plus am looking for a list of books with their set of reviews reduced to the top and bottom 3. Your selects would be useful as subqueries or similar to my query for books, but I have yet to figure out how to get such a thing working. If I do I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

This would typically be done with something like a union, which you can't do in HQL.

You can do this, though, in HQL

```
WHERE id in ([SELECT top 3]) or id in ([SELECT bottom 3])
```

I don't have a way to test this, but this might work too.

```
DetachedCriteria topN = [ your criteria ] 
DetachedCriteria bottomN = [ your criteria ] 

session.createCriteria(..._
    .add( Property.or(Property.forName("id").in(topN),Property.forName("id").in(bottomN) )
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure I can't use your Criteria suggestion as DetachedCriteria does not have a setMaxResults() method, which I need in order to limit the result to the top/bottom 3 (there's actually a request in Hibernate's JIRA site to add this feature). However, I will give your HQL a try.

Comment: It appears what you suggested, and in general, what I want, is impossible with Criteria, HQL, and as far as I can tell even SQL (at least on MySQL). I may flip this problem around and do some pre-processing when a review is saved such that the top/bottom reviews for each book are saved off in a special table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible in MySQL, post your query and I'll take al ook

Comment: MySQL does not support [subselects with limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-errors.html) :-(

Comment: Gah, good catch. Most other dialects support this, I tried it in MSSQL. A nasty solution would be temp tables.  Do post if you find something better

Answer (score 0):

How about do the mapping for Review and Book as many-to-many, and then on Book's reviews collection, specify: order-by="rating desc", and lazy="true"

Supposedly with lazy-fetching method, data will be fetched only when the object are to be fetched from the collection, but I'm not sure about this. To confirm, you can turn on the Hibernate SQL logging and monitor which queries have been made during runtime.

Comment: I need both the top and bottom Reviews, so this doesn't quite work. See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two HQL queries using org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable like:

before in the middle-layer-service you create pageable and call repo:

```
Pageable pageableTop = new PageRequest(0, 3, Direction.ASC, "yourFieldToSortBy");
yourRepository.findTopOrderByYourEntity(pageableTop);

Pageable pageableBottom = new PageRequest(0, 3, Direction.DESC, "yourFieldToSortBy");
yourRepository.findTopOrderByYourEntity(pageableBottom);
```

the repo:

```
public interface YourRepository extends CrudRepository<YourEntity, String> {

    @Query("FROM YourEntity")
    List<YourEntity> findTopOrderByYourEntity(Pageable pageable);
}
```