# Hibernate: how to select last N rows in ascending order of id? (in single query)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-5.x

Hibernate version: 5.2

I am trying to use subqueries to do, and use setMaxResults(int).

```
session.createQuery(
"FROM ( SELECT * FROM tickets ORDER BY id DESC limit 3) sub ORDER BY id ASC"
);
```

However, HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses, and limit can't be used in hibernate.

How can I do it in hibernate?

---

Update - To make it clear

For eg, there are 10 data entries from id=1 to id=10.

I want to select last 3 data in ascending order of id by **only one query** + **without further data processing**.

The result from db would be id=8 to id=10

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Select Top and Bottom n Rows with Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887643/hibernate-select-top-and-bottom-n-rows-with-criteria)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That post just get last bottom n rows but not in ascending order of id. And I don't want two queries and then mix it. I want one single query to get data from db without processing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the ids `1` to `10` and you want the last `N=3`.

Taken your approach

```
SELECT * FROM tickets ORDER BY id DESC
```

would return the ids in order from `10` to `1`. You then want to get the last `N=3` in ascending order. Which means you want the ids `3` to `1` in ascending order.

What would be wrong with selecting the first `N` ids in ascending order?

```
session.createQuery(
    "FROM tickets ORDER BY id ASC"
).setMaxResults(n);
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. This is not what I mean. I have updated the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Query setFirstResult(int startPosition)`, `Query setMaxResults(int maxResult)` to implement it. Typically used in the pagination.

Opportunistic, you can get the first 3 record descendingly here, so you can only use the `Query setMaxResults(int maxResult)`.

Comment: I think it only works on constant database. for eg, QUERY.setFirstResult(6).setMaxResults(3). Did I get you wrong?In case of dynamic database, is it possible to get int startPosition without an extra query?